# Android Printing directly to network printer?

Tags: java, android, printing

Hii in my application I want to send my data directly to my network printer from my Android phone to print it. How can I do that?

I also want to provide specifications like layout, copies, page range, etc. How can I detect my printers directly from my Android phone and also give print command?

Comment: Are you using bluetooth printer ???

Comment: I already wrote an application which writes to bluetooth printers. In that case you only have to pair the phone with the device and after that you just open a socket and write data to it.

Comment: @sujit i am using a network printer

Answer (score 1):

You just need to submit your doccument to the google cloud print. Here is the code that I have used to print. The doccument is saved in external storage and is in pdf form. The only requirement is that both device and wireless printer must be in same network. If the printer is wired, the android device and the system connected to the printer must be logged in with same google account.

```
PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) Order_Bag.this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
String jobName = Order_Bag.this.getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";
//printManager.print(jobName, pda, null);
pda = new PrintDocumentAdapter(){

    @Override
    public void onWrite(PageRange[] pages, ParcelFileDescriptor destination, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback callback){
        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;

        try {

            input = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/hello.pdf");
            output = new FileOutputStream(destination.getFileDescriptor());

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = input.read(buf)) > 0) {
                output.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            callback.onWriteFinished(new PageRange[]{PageRange.ALL_PAGES});

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ee){
            //Catch exception
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Catch exception
        } finally {
            try {
                input.close();
                output.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras){

        if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
            callback.onLayoutCancelled();
            return;
        }

        //    int pages = computePageCount(newAttributes);

        PrintDocumentInfo pdi = new PrintDocumentInfo.Builder("The invoice").setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT).build();

        callback.onLayoutFinished(pdi, true);
    }
};

printManager.print(jobName, pda, null);
```